# How to aggregate a boolean field with null values with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'm working with pandas for the first time and I'm having some issues with aggregation. I have a dataframe with three calculated fields added by an apply statement like this:

```
dataset['calculated_field'] = dataset.apply(
    lambda row: calculation_function(
        row['field1'],
        row['field2']
    ),
    axis = 1
)
```

The calculated fields are booleans, but with a catch. They can contain null values.

I am trying to find the average of the boolean columns, with each average ignoring the null fields for that column.

I've tried something like this:

```
resultset = dataset.groupby(['grouping_field'])[['calculated_field','calculated_field_2','calculated_field_3']].mean()
```

The problem is that since the True/False/None boolean is an "object" type, pandas drops the columns entirely as a [“nuisance” column.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).

I can't convert the column to a bool, though, because it makes the null values "False"

I also tried the long route and created 3 seperate dataframes for each aggregate, so I could drop the null values and convert to bool (which can be aggregated):

```
dataset_for_field1 = dataset.dropna(subset = ['calculated_field']).copy()
dataset_for_field1['calculated_field'] = dataset_for_field1['calculated_field'].astype('bool')

result_for_field1 = dataset_for_field1.groupby(['grouping_field'])['calculated_field'].mean()
```

This gives me the data I'm looking for, but in three separate dataframes.

Is there a way to get one dataframe with the average of each column, ignoring nulls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert them to numeric columns.  The `None` will become `NaN`, `True`s become `1`, and `False`s become `0`.  A convenient way to convert the whole dataframe is to use `pd.to_numeric` with the `errors` parameter set to `ignore`.  This will leave the grouping column alone because it will error out on move on.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        gcol=list('aaaabbbb'),
        clc1=[True, False, True, None] * 2,
        clc2=[True, False, True, False] * 2,
        clc3=[True, True, True, True] * 2,
        clc4=[False, None, None, True]* 2
    ))
```

This is what converting to numeric looks like

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

   clc1   clc2  clc3  clc4 gcol
0   1.0   True  True   0.0    a
1   0.0  False  True   NaN    a
2   1.0   True  True   NaN    a
3   NaN  False  True   1.0    a
4   1.0   True  True   0.0    b
5   0.0  False  True   NaN    b
6   1.0   True  True   NaN    b
7   NaN  False  True   1.0    b
```

Using this with the subsequent `groupby` should get you what you want.

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').groupby('gcol').mean()

          clc1  clc2  clc3  clc4
gcol                            
a     0.666667   0.5   1.0   0.5
b     0.666667   0.5   1.0   0.5
```

Comment: The numeric conversion was exactly what was needed. Thank you for your help!